# Mostrar web en función de un almacén

Tags: java, mysql, angular6

estoy desarrollando una aplicación full-stack mediante angular 6 para el front-end y java para el back-end. Básicamente la aplicación es muy simple y realiza operaciones CRUD sobre una base de datos MySQL. La comunicación entre front-end y back-end la hago a través de servicios REST.

He realizado todas las operaciones necesarias para gestionar los elementos de un almacén (mostrar artículos en la web, añadir, editar, borrar y otras operaciones). Ahora quiero poder trabajar sobre n almacenes. Ya he hecho los cambios pertinentes en BD para poder soportar n almacenes.

Mi duda viene en la parte de Angular. Querría que si, por ejemplo, un operario del almacén A utiliza la web, vea solo los datos del almacén A. Mientras que si la utiliza un operario del almacén B, vea solo los datos de ese almacén. Una solución que se me ocurre es crear un formulario de login y en función del usuario, se muestren los datos de un almacén u otro. En concreto estoy trabajando con Angular 6, ¿de qué manera puedo llevar a cabo esta acción con Angular 6?

Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Revisa [ask] tu pregunta parece basada en opiniones y por tal terminará cerrada

Comment: Hola acabo de revisar https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask y no entiendo porqué no está bien formulada mi pregunta. Es la primera pregunta que hago en stack overflow y me gustaría saber qué es lo que no está correcto en mi formulación.

Comment: La última parte donde preguntas una estrategia, es solicitar opiniones y eso está penalizado por qué las preguntas deben ser claras y no basarse en juicios

Comment: Intentaré ser más específico la próxima vez, pero sinceramente sigo sin entender tu aclaración shadow. Cuando pregunto por una estrategia, me refiero a preguntar por una técnica que pueda utilizar para el problema que planteo. Y entiendo que siempre que las personas responden están dando su opinión, ¿no? Insisto en este punto porque, de forma muy sincera, me gustaría formalizar bien mis preguntas y que también puedan ser útiles para el resto de miembros, gracias por la comprensión.

Comment: En realidad, el tuto que tenias que leer sobre el sitio es el [tour]. Tu pregunta es clara, pero se basa en opiniones. Las respuestas por lo general son opiniones pero cuando esto lleva a debate es cuando se considera que se basa en opiniones. Ademas, esta pregunta no tiene una respuesta unica. Y eso es lo que trata de hacerse en este sitio. Bienvenido!!! y siempre podes [edit] tu pregunta, y cambiar todo lo que haga falta en ella.

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta, ¿se adapta mejor ahora a las normas de stack overflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurren varias posibilidades. En cualquiera lo mejor es que agregues un servicio para indicarle a Angular el almacen que puede ver ese operario.
Una opción es mostrar con *ngIf algo tipo:

```
/* if almacen_id == opera_en_id(Por ejemplo el operario X opera en almacen A) */
 <div *ngIf="myService.currentUser.almacen_id">
   // tu almacen... podria ser <app-almacen></app-almacen> y tenerlo en otro componente ...
 </div>
```

Otra posibilidad es en routes algo tipo:

```
  {
    path: 'almacen',
    component: AlmacenComponent,
    canActivate: [OperarioService],
    children: [
         { path: ':id', component: AlmacenDetailComponent },
       ]
  },
```

Donde OperarioService es tu servicio del usuario logueado con sus headers y donde AlmacenDetailComponent es el almacen específico para ese usuario. Lo que haces con canActivate es restringir el uso de esa ruta a ese usuario y nadie más.
Inclusive podés combinar lo primero con esto segundo para restringir desde las rutas por seguridad.

Espero que te sirva como estrategia. Si te llevas mejor con Java que con Angular podrías programar desde la API una devolución del almacen para el usuario logueado, de modo que en Angular sólo tengas que hacer el GET con el operario logueado y la API responda con su almacen específico.

Comment: Favor de no responder preguntas basadas en opiniones

Comment: Gracias por la pronta respuesta. ¿Podría también lanzar la aplicación angular con un parámetro para que si, por ejemplo, le paso 1 me muestre la web para almacén A y si le paso 2 me la muestre para almacén B?